# MTM Direct Links Query vs Query-based suit (direct-links)

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

Direct Links query can be created two ways in MTM

1. Plan->Contents->New Query-based suite->(query type)->Work Items and Direct Links
2. Track->Queries->New Direct-Link Query

First one creates a test suite in the end. Is there any other difference?

Answer (score 1):

Your two techniques are doing different things and have different purposes.

Option 2 is simply doing a Work Item Query, the same way you can do in Team Explorer/Visual Studio and also Team Web Access.

Once you have viewed the information you can discard it or save it in "My Queries" or "Shared Queries".  If you save it, you can view the results in Excel for example or perhaps share it with colleagues.

Option 1 is all about creating a Test Suite which is a grouping of Test Cases.

There are static suites which are essentially folders for grouping Test Cases.

There are requirements based suites - for example, add all the PBIs from Sprint 1 and then we can add Test Cases to ensure we have tested against their acceptance criteria.

Then there are query based suites which will add all the test cases which match your specified query.  New test cases will be added if they match the query (eg. all high priority test cases)

[Organizing Test Cases Using Test Suites(2012)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286738(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, if you want a test plan then use option 1.  If you want to simply run queries, use option 2 (or use team explorer/web access to do the same thing)